# POSTGIS: find all the points within a polygon

Tags: postgresql, postgis, polygons, point-in-polygon

I have a table containing point

```
CREATE TABLE Points
{
  pointID BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  thePoint GEOGRAPHY(POINT)
}

CREATE TABLE Polygons
{
  polygonID BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  aPolygon GEOGRAPHY(POLYGON) NOT NULL,
}
```

I wish to find all the points that are contained in each polygon.
i.e the result should look like

```
polygonID| pointID
-------------------
1        | 1
1        | 2
1        | 5
1        | 7
2        | 2
2        | 3
...
```

I managed to go point by point and to figure out if it's in the polygon using `ST_CoveredBy(thePoint, aPolygon)`. Based on that the naive solution is going in a nested loop over all points and polygons but for sure there is a more efficient and correct way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way, which works on geography types. BTW, might be worth reading the [manual](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/) on geometry and geography data types. As far as I understand it, there are many more functions available for geometries, but you have to get involved with projections. The best choice depends on what you're doing...

```
SELECT polygonID, pointID
  FROM Points INNER JOIN Polygons 
  ON ST_covers(polygons.aPolygon,Points.thePoint  );
```

Answer (score 1):

postgresql has `polygon @> point`

```
select * from points join polygons on polygons.aPolygon @> points.thePoint;
```

Comment: @> gave me an error. Also, @ doesn't work with geography data type. Finally, @Aleksandar Stojadinovic is right - @ only considers bounding boxes...

Comment: <@ will work correctly (not limited to bounding boxes), at least for geometry types.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was sort-of in your question: "within". Use the [ST_DWithin operator](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html).

```
SELECT polygonID, pointID
FROM Points
JOIN Polygons ON ST_DWithin(Points.thePoint, polygons.aPolygon, 0);
```

The last argument `0` is the distance within the polygon. This is useful to also select points that are, for example, within 10 m of the polygon, which is useful if there are positioning errors in the source data.

`ST_Intersects(Points.thePoint, polygons.aPolygon)` should also work.

See [DE-9IM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM) if you want to learn more on what these operators mean, but not all have geography type equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

It's been some time now since I've done anything with PostGIS, but I'll give it a try.

`SELECT polygonID, pointID
  FROM Points, Polygons
  WHERE ST_CONTAINS(Points.thePoint , polygonID.aPolygon);`

Comment: ST_CONTAINS never worked for me always get the following error: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. ST_CoveredBy and ST_Intersects work.

Comment: Ok, I haven't tested the example, I might have missed something. Is there any issue with using the CoveredBy method? You can greatly improve your performance if you use indexing (if you are not already). The ST_* methods in PostGIS can utilize them automatically.

Comment: st_contains only works on geometry types rather than geography types. @liva that might be the reason for your error. Note also the difference between st_contains and st_covers - http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.de/2007/06/subtleties-of-ogc-covers-spatial.html. Finally, the arguments are in the wrong order - i.e. you'd need st_covers(polygons.apolygon, points.thepoint)