# Filter Rails records to within geo-polygonal area using latitude/longitude

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, geospatial, raycasting

In my Rails app I have search areas, which are geographic polygons (created using the Google Maps API). Once drawn on the map, the search area's coordinates are saved to a record as an array of hashes. It looks something like this:

```
SearchArea.last.geo
=> [{"lat"=>"48.425555463221066", "lng"=>"-123.3793830871582"}, {"lat"=>"48.41336528699442", "lng"=>"-123.37800979614258"}, {"lat"=>"48.41006090395106", "lng"=>"-123.31672668457031"}, {"lat"=>"48.44696663691928", "lng"=>"-123.32067489624023"}]
```

I also have a handful of location records whose coordinates are saved as a hash, like so:

```
Location.last.geo
=> {"lat"=>"28.8138124", "lng"=>"-96.9977682"}
```

I need to be able to search for/filter records that have geo coordinates that fall within a given search area. I have no experience with geospatial programming, so I'm hoping someone can lend a hand here. It would be really appreciated!

Things I've looked in to:

- I know the Google Maps API has a [Geometry Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry?hl=en). Unfortunately this is client side.
- I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303568/detect-if-point-in-latitude-longitude-based-polygon) answer, which led to [this](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/) article, but it is written in C.
- [This article](http://jakescruggs.blogspot.ca/2009/07/point-inside-polygon-in-ruby.html) from 2009 has some code that looks like it should work, but I'm not sure how I would implement it using latitude/longitude coordinates.
- [This wiki page](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ray-casting_algorithm) has a whole bunch of implementations of Ray-casting in various languages, but again, I'm not sure how to implement it in Ruby/Rails.

Comment: Not sure how helpful this is, but PostGis can search by polygon - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830521/postgis-find-all-the-points-within-a-polygon - and be used in Rails - http://ngauthier.com/2013/08/postgis-and-rails-a-simple-approach.html

Comment: MongoDB also supports "polygonal" geospatial queries. What database are you looking to use? https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-geospatial/

Comment: The PostGis thing looks cool, might check that out. I'm running PostgreSQL. Would ideally like to not rip the DB apart, but if that's my only option I'll give it a whirl!

Comment: Hey Nate, PostGis ended up being incredibly difficult to work with but well worth it in the end. Thanks for the suggestion! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nate suggested PostGis in the comments above, so I went with that.

I ended up using [this tutorial](http://daniel-azuma.com/articles/georails/part-2) to install PostGis on my Rails app, with some minor changes for 2016:

- The line where it says to add `require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgis_adapter/railtie'` should actually be `require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgis_adapter'`
- The syntax for creating a geo table columns has changed from `t.point :latlon, :geographic => true` to `t.geography "latlon", limit: {:srid=>4326, :type=>"point", :geographic=>true}`
- Based on [this issue](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter/issues/185) I also added the following initializer:

  ```
  RGeo::ActiveRecord::SpatialFactoryStore.instance.tap do |config|
    config.default = RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326)
  end
  ```

The rest of the tutorial was a pretty good reference, from installing the gems to updating the database configuration.

From there I was then able to create a Location with a `Point`:

```
Location.last.geo = "POINT(-123.366 48.428)"
```

As well as my polygonal area to search within using a `Polygon`:

```
SearchArea.last.geo = "POLYGON((-123.382 48.426, -123.353 48.402, -123.314 48.423, -123.332 48.443, -123.382 48.426))"
```

Finally, the query; it was so simple!

```
sa = SearchArea.last
Location.where("ST_Intersects(geo, '#{sa.geo}')")
```

Thanks for the suggestion, Nate!